# Cannot revert lightdm to gdm3

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, display-manager

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my HP laptop. This morning after restart it wasn't able to find my second monitor, which is connected via HDMI. I had those issues before, and fixed them by restarting multiple times, connecting HDMI to my TV etc, but this time it did not work.

I have found the answer on stackoverflow to switch to `lightdm` as a solution to my problem. I installed `lightdm` with `apt-get`, ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and restarted the computer.

New appearence was there, other monitor on HDMI was also there. I encountered next problems :

- My battery indicator was not showing how much I have left (stuck at 48%) and wasnt showing when I plug charger that it is charging
- Title buttons were on the left side of windows, which is not what I am accustomed to since I also have other computer running Windows.

So I started googling to fixing that, I have **Tweaks** installed, but when selecting right/left position it only affected the Tweaks window, others were still with buttons on left side. I have tried (found it on stackoverflow also)

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'`

which didnt have the effect, also found on some answer

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DecorationLayout':<':minimize,maximize,close'>}"`

but that also didnt work, the title buttons were still on the left side.

After that I completely removed `lightdm`, purged, restarted, `gdm3` login screen appeared but the desctop appearence was the same as when using `lightdm`, still battery icon issue and still buttons on the left side. I have tried than installing `lightdm` and removing/purging `gdm3` but the issue remained the same.

Help would be appreciated, since I cannot just accept buttons on the left side and ignore battery icon, and reinstalling OS would be super painful since I have tons of stuff set (I use laptop for sotware development)

Comment: At this point reinstalling would probably be faster and cleaner than just trying to get display managers working properly. I would recommend just making a list of all the software you've installed and making a copy of your `/home` folder and reinstalling, and copying those over/reinstalling your software. `/home` will be as you left it and reinstalling shouldn't be too long unless you had compiled stuff from source which you'll need to do again. It will be painful, but not as painful as getting GNOME working again... speaking of which I recommend moving to KDE which has none of these headaches